# Do While loop causing compile failure

Tags: c#, do-while

I am attempting to make a simple geography quiz program in C# (Visual studio 2013). I can get most of it, however I need to detect when a user has selected an answer and pushed the "Enter" button. To this end, I use a do-while loop wait for the user to complete both of these requirements before proceeding, however when the do-wile loop is added it fails to compile. By fail I mean that the compile never gives an error and stops, or does anything at all, and merely sits there. I have tried commenting out the do-while loop and it compiles fine, so the error must be with that. What am I missing?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int anselct = 0;
    bool buttonclick = false;
    bool runme = true;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Q1.Text = Q1.Text.Replace("null", "Hello, welcome to the Geography quiz. Press 'A' and then 'Enter' to begin the quiz."); //replaces base text with introduction
        A1.Text = A1.Text.Replace("radioButton1", "A");
        A2.Text = A2.Text.Replace("radioButton3", "B");
        A3.Text = A3.Text.Replace("radioButton4", "C");
        A4.Text = A4.Text.Replace("radioButton2", "D");
        do {
            if (A1.Checked && buttonclick == true)
            {
                buttonclick = false;
                Q1.Text = Q1.Text.Replace("Hello, welcome to the Geography quiz. Press 'A' and then 'Enter' to begin the quiz.", "Question 1: What is the capital of Cuba"); //Changes text to that of the first question
                A1.Text = A1.Text.Replace("A", "Greenwich");
                A2.Text = A2.Text.Replace("B", "Berlin");
                A3.Text = A3.Text.Replace("C", "Bogota");
                A4.Text = A4.Text.Replace("D", "Havana");
                runme = false;
            } //end of if statement
       } while (runme == true); //end of do loop, should be infinate unless told to close
    }
```

//various irrelevant things are here

```
    public void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonclick = true;
    }  //end of Button_Click_1
}
```

Comment: is `A1` ever checked? sounds like an infinite loop. have you set breakpoints and stepped through the code?

Comment: I have to be honest, I can't see this being the case. If it is, the C# compiler is broken. Which I doubt. Are you sure you don't mean it hangs at run-time? As an aside, this is not the recommended way of checking states. You should be using event handlers, but that's another issue.

Comment: @user1666620 - he said the issue is at compile-time.

Comment: This isn't how you write WinForms apps.  You can't just set up an infinite loop to poll for changes, it will hang.  You *react to events*, you don't poll until something happens.  You code could be called by your button click handler, for example.  I suggest reading some basic tutorials.

Comment: @JayMee: I'm pretty sure he's wrong.  It compiles and starts, but the UI never appears because the constructor never terminates.

Comment: I can tell you that the do..while loop is working. your code must be out of the constructor and this is loop that never end ... infinite loop because A1 is not checked forever \

Comment: @JayMee i think he's just mixing up compile time and runtime.

Comment: I suspected so, maybe I'm being too pedantic.

Comment: I suppose, actually, it *could* possibly appear like it's the compiler if you're not overly familiar with it. If a form's constructor hangs on a loop infinitely, it may not appear at all IIRC (been a while since winforms).

Comment: Yep, Im quite new to this language, the error was obvious as expected, thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: It's a real pain that Visual Studio Designer window actually creates instances of the form causing the constructor to be called - so if there are problems there it does look like compiler problems. On several projects I have added the following code after the call to InitializeComponent _"if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) return;"_

Answer (score 2):

Based on the assumption you meant 'run-time' instead of 'compile-time', I'll address the 'hanging'.

```
public void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(A1.Checked)
    {   
       ReplaceText();
    }
}

private void ReplaceText()
{
    Q1.Text = Q1.Text.Replace("Hello, welcome to the Geography quiz. Press 'A' and then 'Enter' to begin the quiz.", "Question 1: What is the capital of Cuba"); //Changes text to that of the first question
    A1.Text = A1.Text.Replace("A", "Greenwich");
    A2.Text = A2.Text.Replace("B", "Berlin");
    A3.Text = A3.Text.Replace("C", "Bogota");
    A4.Text = A4.Text.Replace("D", "Havana");
}
```

**Explanation**

Compile-time is the point in time at which the C# compiler **builds** your code. i.e. it assembles it ready for when it is called/ran.

When it is ran, you are now in **runtime**.

Compile-time errors tend to happen when your compiler finds errors in your syntax (generally, there are other scenarios).

Runtime errors (again, generally, in a nutshell) happen in code that has built fine (so is syntactically sound), but has logic errors due to the path it has executed or any number of environment variables.

Events, in this case, are things that happen as a result of the user interacting with the UI. You have successfully wired up a button event handler and that's great, so it is in there that you should trigger off some functionality. You don't need to put these checks in place yourself by polling it as fast and frequent as possible.

**The Hanging Issue**

Your application has 'stopped' while it's running the loop. It must finish the loop before it moves onto the rest of your code, but you've given it no reason to finish the loop. So it loops and loops, infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wipe out your loop you build up a infinite loop in your constructor.

Try to use the Events of you Form like Charles Mager wrote in a comment.

You can find some information about Events here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is the end-less loop inside your constructor, as others already pointed out in the comments, I suggest you change your program to an event-driven way. something like below:

```
namespace Photoviewer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int anselct = 0;
        //bool buttonclick = false;
        //bool runme = true;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Q1.Text = Q1.Text.Replace("null", "Hello, welcome to the Geography quiz. Press 'A' and then 'Enter' to begin the quiz."); //replaces base text with introduction
            A1.Text = A1.Text.Replace("radioButton1", "A");
            A2.Text = A2.Text.Replace("radioButton3", "B");
            A3.Text = A3.Text.Replace("radioButton4", "C");
            A4.Text = A4.Text.Replace("radioButton2", "D");

        }

//various irrelevant things are here

        public void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (A1.Checked)
                {                       
                    Q1.Text = Q1.Text.Replace("Hello, welcome to the Geography quiz. Press 'A' and then 'Enter' to begin the quiz.", "Question 1: What is the capital of Cuba"); //Changes text to that of the first question
                    A1.Text = A1.Text.Replace("A", "Greenwich");
                    A2.Text = A2.Text.Replace("B", "Berlin");
                    A3.Text = A3.Text.Replace("C", "Bogota");
                    A4.Text = A4.Text.Replace("D", "Havana");

                }
        }  //end of Button_Click_1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;



namespace Photoviewer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int anselct = 0;
        bool runme = true;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Q1.Text = Q1.Text.Replace("null", "Hello, welcome to the Geography quiz. Press 'A' and then 'Enter' to begin the quiz."); //replaces base text with introduction
            A1.Text = A1.Text.Replace("radioButton1", "A");
            A2.Text = A2.Text.Replace("radioButton3", "B");
            A3.Text = A3.Text.Replace("radioButton4", "C");
            A4.Text = A4.Text.Replace("radioButton2", "D");

        }

//various irrelevant things are here

        public void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //do {
                if (A1.Checked)
                {
                    Q1.Text = Q1.Text.Replace("Hello, welcome to the Geography quiz. Press 'A' and then 'Enter' to begin the quiz.", "Question 1: What is the capital of Cuba"); //Changes text to that of the first question
                    A1.Text = A1.Text.Replace("A", "Greenwich");
                    A2.Text = A2.Text.Replace("B", "Berlin");
                    A3.Text = A3.Text.Replace("C", "Bogota");
                    A4.Text = A4.Text.Replace("D", "Havana");
                    //runme = false;
                } //end of if statement
           //} while (runme == true); //end of do loop, should be infinate unless told to close
        }  //end of Button_Click_1
    }
}
```

Commented the lines out since it wouldn't make sense to just keep looping through on a button click. Basically it's like this: You want to do checks upon the action of an event. Don't sit in the constructor and try to hang it for information. It's not the way Winforms works.